# Optimal way to configure urls that should enforce HTTPS in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, https

is there a way to configure Nginx to read from a line-by-line file to determine when HTTPS should be enforced rather than putting all the URLS in a conditional check? Or is there a way to combine the two? Two areas of concern are organization and the ability long term to manage those urls. We are thinking of moving this to the application layer but Nginx seems faster in evaluating this. Currently we are just using a regular expression.

Comment: Why not just force everything to TLS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map $uri $example_com_preferred_proto {
    default "http";
    ~^/sign-up/ "https";
    ~^/account/ "https";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    if ($example_com_preferred_proto = "https") {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    # root /var/www/example.com/html;
    # other stuff
    # ...
    # location / {
    #     ...
    # }

}
```